# Configuring if statements for better flexibility and scalability?

Tags: c#

So I have two objects of the same type. The object looks like this:

```
public BatchOfStuff(int id, List<Stuff> stuffList)
```

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
if (stuffList1.Any()){
    var batchStuff1 = new BatchOfStuff(1, stuffList1);
    var transformedBatch = typeATransformer.TransformBatch(batchStuff1);
    ValidateTransformedBatch(transformedBatch);
}
if (stuffList2.Any()){
    var batchStuff2 = new BatchOfStuff(2, stuffList2);
    var transformedBatch = typeBTransformer.TransformBatch(batchStuff2);
    ValidateTransformedBatch(transformedBatch);
}
```

As you can see, the stuff in the two if statements are pretty much the same, the only difference being that one uses a TypeATransformer and the other a TypeBTransformer. TypeATransformer and TypeBTransformer both inherit from a base class called Transformer. It is possible that in the future, there will be TypeCTransformers and TypeDTransformers that follow the same pattern as the above. Is it possible for me to not have the duplicated code within the if statements? Thanks!

Comment: Use .Any instead of .Count if you just checking that at-least one element exist.

Comment: How are the transformer types related? You could likely break the contents of the `if`s into a method and leverage common code between the types, but their relationship is unclear.

Comment: @Adrian Why?  If it's a `List<T>` then `Count` is a direct call where as `Any` will have to do casting just to end up doing the same thing.  Now if your using `Enumerable.Count()` then yeah `Any` is better in that case.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb The transformer types takes the lists and routes them down two different paths. What objects belong in what list was determined earlier. However, the actions performed within the transformer types are different based on what kind of stuff should be in the list.

Ex: We have two lists. They are both of type Animal. The Animals are split into the two lists of Animals depending on what type of Animal it is, and are then routed into two different Transformers. What stuff each Transformer does is different based on Animal.

Comment: @juharr Nice catch, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your duplicated code in a function, then call it twice:

```
 public BatchOfStuff ProcessBatch(int id, 
                                  List<Stuff> stuffList,
                                  BatchTransformer transformer)
 {
      if (stuffList1.Any())
      {
          var batchStuff = new BatchOfStuff(id, stuffList);
          var transformedBatch = transformer.TransformBatch(batchStuff);
          ValidateTransformedBatch(transformedBatch);

          return transformedBatch;
      }

      return null;
 }

 var batchStuff1 = ProcessBatch(1, stuffList1, typeATransformer);
 var batchStuff2 = ProcessBatch(2, stuffList2, typeBTransformer);
```

You didnt specify the transformer types - so that part is uncertain - but it will always be possible (one way or another) to reuse this code.